# What public key systems allow for delegation?

Tags: public-key-infrastructure, pgp, smime

I am looking for a public key system that allows for a 3rd party to use that key for other purposes.

What private key systems allow for this? PGP, S/MIME, PKI?

Comment: You mean like [certificate's key usage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509#Extensions_informing_a_specific_usage_of_a_certificate), which are usually set by the CA and define how the certificate owner can use his certificate?

Comment: *That* key specifically, or another key? Because PGP allows vouching for other keys.

Comment: I'm looking for any system that allows for this, I'm trying to determine which ones to research further.

Comment: what is a private key system? you mention a few public key concepts...

Comment: "For other purposes" is very broad. _What exactly_ are your requirements?

Comment: @JensErat I'm working with a zero knowledge proof based PKI and curious if it can lend itself to delegation scenarios.  It's a Bitcoin alternative and I'm evaluating the technology to determine if I should invest in it. I'm trying to evaluate potential